# nodejs FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: node.js, angular, mean-stack

Sometimes occur this error.

```
<--- Last few GCs --->                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 [2856:00000253F09D3B90] 11688472 ms: Mark-sweep 1529.8 (1619.4) -> 1529.7 (1583.4) MB, 1835.6 / 0.0 ms  last resort GC in old space requested  

 [2856:00000253F09D3B90] 11690272 ms: Mark-sweep 1529.7 (1583.4) -> 1529.7 (1579.4) MB, 1799.7 / 0.0 ms  last resort GC in old space requested                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

<--- JS stacktrace --->                                                                                                                                                                                                         
==== JS stack trace =========================================                                                                                                                                                                   
Security context: 000001F6C9E25739 <JSObject>                                                                       
1: completeMany [C:\Users\mobasher.fasihy\Documents\GitHub\jobsaf-server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:~1459] [pc=0000006F3C3482B8](this=0000029E4B604F01 <JSGlobal Object>,model=00000090CCBE6729 <JSFunction model (sfi = 000001A244DDB931)>,docs=0000025B74FA8591 
<JSArray[53714]>,fields=0000025B74FA8FF1 <Object map = 00000207F58823B9>,userProvidedFields=0000025B74FA9029 <Object map = 000...                                                                                                                                                                 
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory                               
1: node::DecodeWrite                                                                                            
2: node_module_register                                                                                         
3: v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory                                                                        
4: v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory                                                                        
5: v8::internal::Factory::NewUninitializedFixedArray                                                            
6: v8::internal::WasmDebugInfo::SetupForTesting                                                                 
7: v8::internal::interpreter::BytecodeArrayRandomIterator::UpdateOffsetFromIndex                                
8: 0000006F3C2043C1                                                                                            
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Randomly above error occur on the server, and app crashes.

Comment: Please post the error message as text in a codeblock, it is easier to search for, read, and use to help you. This error mean you are using too much memory, probably a array you are filling way too much, a recursive call that you don't let breathe, or a loop you let continue for way too long, but without code, we can't go further.

Comment: @DrakaSAN Can't track which request of my application cause this error, it occurs randomly. I have some collections that have more than 60 thousand records, when I list them or search them, sometimes above error occur.

Comment: Look like a good suspect, depending how you list your collection, that may be how you crash everything. Do you use a DB? Which one? How do you use it? If you can, can you post the list and search function?

Comment: @DrakaSAN Yeah I use MongoDB, my list, and the search function is simple, I just use from `find, aggregate, skip, limit, and somewhere $match`. It's response time is good, and all my requests respond fast.

Comment: How long do you keep the data you get? I would log the exact requests, wait for a crash, and investigate what call caused the crash, probably a request for a lot of data at once, or a *huge* object in the DB.

Answer (score 2):

While you can use David's workaround, I d advise to search for the root cause.

There is not a lot of probable cause for Out Of Memory errors:

- A recursive call got so long it broke the stack trace
- You created a extremely heavy object
- You got a lot of data at once

If the root cause is a recursive call, which was a common mistake when node.js was chock full of callback, there was one line that gave the control back to the event loop so it could clear up after itself (`process.nextTick` or something similar)

For the two other cause, which nowadays are the most likely culprit, especially when using a DB, you will need to either use streams, so that you never get the full data at once in memory, or find another way to divide the work.

Answer (score 0):

Which process is throwing the error?

Try setting the `max_old_space_size` setting (in MB)

```
node --max_old_space_size=4096 <yourScriptHere>
```

Comment: `yourFile`? what should be here.

Comment: The script that you are starting with node

Comment: @David Do u mean something like npm run dev? Or am I getting it wrong